# $\int_C ydx+z^2dy+xdz$ on a specific curve

Tags: integration, curves

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_C ydx+z^2dy+xdz$$ 
>   on a specific curve, the intersection between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=6-(x^2+y^2)$.

I don't know how to parametrize this, also it seems wrong to me if I subtitute $z^2$ in the second one i get the equation $z=6-z^2\implies z=2$ since $z\geq0$. what do I do with this..? Also is there some kind of way to always approach these questions where you have to integrate between 2 surfaces?

Comment: The hint below should be helpful. Once you figure out the curve given by the equations $x^2 + y^2 = 2^2$ and $z=2$, you can parametrize it by using $r(t)= \langle x(t), y(t), z(t) \rangle = \langle 2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, 2 \rangle$, where  $0\leq t < 2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. $z=2$ tells you that the curve $C$ is contained in the plane $z=2$. Moreover $z=6−(x^2+y^2)$ (or $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) implies that $x^2+y^2=6-2=2^2$. What kind of curve is this? It should be easy to get a parametrization now and evaluate
$$\int_C ydx+z^2dy+xdz.$$

Comment: It's a circle, but when I get one of the variables as a number into the equation I should just think that it is in that specific plane?

Comment: And also $dz = 0$? I just simply take: 

$$x=2cost$$
$$y=2sint$$
$$z=2$$
?

Comment: Yes, it is the circle centered at $(0,0,2)$ of radius $2$ contained in the plane $z=2$. Yes, $dz=0$.

Comment: Yes, the parametrization is correct with $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! Also can you give me some tips for when I have to integrate when I am gives 2 equations like that?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the two equations. In this case, your approach was the right one.